# Error/Warning parsing RSS XML :(

Tags: xml, rss, simplexml, php

I did this

```
<blink>
$xml = file_get_contents(http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12797541);
$yahoo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml , 0, true);
</blink>
```

And I got an XML parse warning like this:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct()
[<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]:
I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;
```

.....

With an important part of the message being this:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

And I could not parse anything with this line:

```
echo (string) $yahoo_response->rss->channel->item->title;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or get around it?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3rd argument of `SimpleXMLElement()` specifies if `$data` is URL. You should do either

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12797541');
$yahoo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml , 0, false); // false, not true
```

or

```
$xml = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12797541'; // url, not contents
$yahoo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml , 0, true);
```

Comment: That fixed the error and warning.  Thank you.  But how come I still don't get anything returned from echo $yahoo_response->rss->channel->item->title;

Comment: I'm not sure (haven't worked with SimpleXML for some time), but I believe that `$yahoo_response` points to `<rss/>` element. Try printing `$yahoo_response->channel->item->title`. You should also have a look at manual (http://lv.php.net/SimpleXMLElement).